# Probability Distribution2

Tags: probability

Suppose that a 6-sided die is rolled    times. Let    be the value of the top face at the   th roll, and let  ≜max1≤≤  be the highest value observed. For example, if  =3  and the three rolls are 4, 1, and 4, then  1=4,2=1,3=4  and  =4 .

To find the distribution of   , observe first that  ≤  iff  ≤  for all  1≤≤ , hence  (≤)=(/6) . It follows that  (=)=(≤)−(≤−1)=(/6)−((−1)/6) . For example,  (=1)=(1/6) , and  (=2)=(1/3)−(1/6) .

In this problem we assume that each of the    dice has a potentially different number of faces, denoted   , and ask you to write a function largest_face that determines the probability  ()  that the highest top face observed is   . largest_face takes a vector    of positive integers, interpreted as the number of faces of each of the dice, and a value    and returns  () . For example, if  =[2,5,7] , then three dice are rolled, and  (1)=(1/2)⋅(1/5)⋅(1/7)  as all dice must be 1, while  (7)=1/7  as the third die must turn up 7.

Sample run *

print largest_face([2,5,8],8)
print largest_face([2], 1)
largest_face( [3,4], 2)
print largest_face([2, 5, 7, 3], 3)

Answer (score 1):

If $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)\in\mathbb Z_{>0}^n$ and $X=\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ then using the same technique sketched in your question we find for $k\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$  that:$$\begin{aligned}P\left(X=k\right) & =P\left(X\leq k\right)-P\left(X\leq k-1\right)\\
 & =\prod_{i=1}^{n}P\left(X_{i}\leq k\right)-\prod_{i=1}^{n}P\left(X_{i}\leq k-1\right)\\
 & =\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\min\left(k,f_{i}\right)}{f_{i}}-\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\min\left(k-1,f_{i}\right)}{f_{i}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Does this indeed answer your question?